# In regards to memory usage, what are buffers?

Tags: memory

Just took a look at the memory usage (with `free -m`) on one of my Ubuntu servers and saw this:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           751        624        127          0        256        236
-/+ buffers/cache:        131        619
Swap:          299          0        299
```

1. What is a buffer?
2. If something needed RAM to process something, would a buffer give up its allotment (like cache would)?
3. Is there any way I can find what's using the 256MB of memory for buffer?
4. Should I be worried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The developers of the linux memory management have a [short technical description](http://linux-mm.org/Low_On_Memory) of it (look for the "Buffer Cache" topic).
2. Buffers that aren't needed at the moment can make way for more urgent memory needs.
3. The kernel is using it.
4. No.